# Size of infinte sets cardinality

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The question is as follows:

Prove that if R is uncountable and T is a countable subset of R, then the cardinality of R\T is the same as the cardinality of R.

What i have:

I know that R is uncountable so it has a countable subset (this is a theorem of uncountable sets). Let T be this subset so T has the same cardinality as the set of natural numbers(by the definition of T being countable). My intution is telling me that we will have to use the cantor bernstein theorem to prove they have same cardinalities. So for that the first thing i did showed was that |R\T| <= |R| (pretty clear as its  R\T, |R| means cardinality of R).i got a bit confused while trying to show that |R| <= |R\T|. Maybe we can show this by defining a bijection f from R --> R\T, such that f(x) = x when x is in R\T, but i dont know what to do if x is in R and not in R\T, if i can define that function then i can conclude |R| <= |R\T|, then use the cantor-bernstein theorem and then im done. Or maybe im doing this all wrong i cant think of any other way Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: What does "countable" mean in this question? Some authors use "countable" to mean "has the same cardinality as $\mathbb  N$", others use "countable" to mean "has at most the cardinality of $\mathbb N$". Are finite sets "countable" for you?

Comment: same cardinality as N, yes finite sets are countable

Comment: You just gave two contradictory answers to my question: (1) countable sets have the same cardinality as $\mathbb N$ and (2) finite sets are countable. (A finite sets does **not** have the same cardinality as $\mathbb N$.)

Comment: yes that is true, what i meant to say was that in this question countable means has the SAME cardinality as N, and finite sets are countable but they do not have same cardinality as N which is true like you said

Comment: Your replies continue to contradict themselves. When you say that $T$ is a countable subset of $N$, is it safe to assume that $T$ is infinite? Or could $T$ be a finite set?

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find a quite nice bijection between $R$ and $R\setminus T$, actually. I would go at it like so:

1. Prove that $R\setminus T$ is uncountable
2. Conclude that there must exist some countable $T_1\subseteq R\setminus T$, with $|T_1|=|T|$.
3. From there, we can find some countable $T_2\subseteq R\setminus (T\cup T_1)$, and continue from there to find countable $T_1,T_2,T_3,\dots T_n,\dots$, such that for each $n$, we have $T_n\subseteq R\setminus(T\cup T_1\cup\cdots\cup T_{n-1})$
4. Now, we can map the values of $x\in T$ to elements in $T_1$, elements in $T_1$ to $T_2$, and so on. All values not in any of $T_i$ get mapped to themselves.

Comment: Omg thank you so much!! i get it now i didnt even think  about the countable subsets of T since T is countable itself. Appreciate it!!

Comment: @Johm I am not talking about the countable subsets of $T$. I am talking about the countable subsets of $R\setminus T$.

Comment: I was literally misreading the entire thing God. But i understand it

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be a countable subset of an uncountable set $R$.

Since $R$ is uncountable and $T$ is countable, it follows that $R\setminus T$ is uncountable. Therefore, there is a countably infinite set $S\subseteq R\setminus T$. Then $S\cup T$ is also a countably infinite set. Therefore there is a bijection
$$f:S\to S\cup T.$$
Of course there is a trivial bijection
$$g:R\setminus(S\cup T)\to R\setminus(S\cup T).$$
The union of these two bijections is a bijection
$$f\cup g:R\setminus T\to R.$$